# Log4Net not writing to Windows EventViewer

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, event-viewer

I went so far as creating a test console app project to see how log4Net works and why it's not working on my real world application but it doesn't even write on the console app.

my app.config looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <configSections>
   <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
  </configSections>
<log4net>
 <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender,log4net">
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
   </layout>
 </appender>
 <root>
   <level value="ALL"/>
   <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
 </root>
 <logger name="EventViewerLogger">
   <level value="ALL"/>
   <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
 </logger>
 </log4net>
</configuration>
```

and my method looks like this

```
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            //log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();
            //log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(new EventLogAppender { ApplicationName = "Log4NetTEST", LogName = "EchoEnterprise" });

            var log = LogManager.GetLogger("EventViewerLogger");
            //var log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Class1));

            var t = log.Logger.Repository.GetAppenders();

            log.Info("Test INFO from Jamboree");

            Console.WriteLine("Log4Net hopefuly worked!");
```

So when i try the 1st (uncommented) version of "Configure", it states that it cannot find the log4net configurations in my app, but it's obviously there. it even tells me how it's supposed to look. it states

```
log4net:ERROR Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file. Check your .config file for the <log4net> and <configSections> elements. The configuration section should look like: <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
```

the second version (commented) is the default and it DOES log to the Console. I want it to go to the EventViewer though

The third one (commented) does nothing but provides one appender (verified by the 't' variable). 
None of these, however, log in the Event Viewer
- I have opened VS (2012) and EventViewer both in Administrator mode.
- I've tried pretty much every permutation of commented/uncommented code and still no log in Event Viewer. Any help would be appreciated as i feel like it;s right under my nose. Thanks in advance.

ALSO (UPDATE) - added the following line in the AssemblyInfo.cs file

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

but still does not log in Event Viewer

Comment: looking at the docs quickly the appender line doesn't have the ',log4net' at the end its just `<appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >` could this be the problem?

Comment: no, it does indeed. I just wanted to be sure that's what I copied/pasted and that no one edited my origional post, but it's also in my local VS2012 solution as well.

FURTHERMORE, I have also added <paraam> elements to place the Logname and ApplicationName 's but with the same result

Comment: @Jacobr365 the `,log4net` is just specifying which assembly (DLL) to find the class in.

Comment: Try running as administrator.  I just tested a simple hello world app with roughly your app.config and it only logs to event viewer when you run it as administrator.

Comment: @ebyrob, I've opened both Visual Studio and Event Viewer in Administrator mode and still nothing. since it looks to work on your machine with config, I wonder if it is my machine. Nonetheless, still no go

Comment: @ebyrob Running as Admin once should be enough. You need admin rights to create an event source, but once it is created, you can write to the event log

Comment: There's a log4net FAQ entry for this, [Why doesn't the EventLogAppender work?](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#trouble-EventLog)

Comment: @user2403316 Did you try everything with the `ConsoleAppender` first, then once it's working just change the classname to `EventLogAppender`?  i.e.: use your exact configuration as it is, just change `log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender` to `log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender`.  Get that working first.

Comment: Would recommend enabling log4net debugging (ie `<log4net debug="true">`) and you should see any error message in VS output window. Also set  your applicationName ie `<param name="ApplicationName" value="MyApp" />` otherwise the event source will be different when debugging from inside VS than running outside.

Comment: BTW, BasicConfigurator only ever uses the ConsoleAppender, so you need to use XmlConfigurator.

Comment: @ebryob, just tried the 'ConsoleAdapter' switch. nothing different.@sgmoore, I had the <param name="ApplicationName" value="MyApp" /> thing as well (just not in the example above) that did not work either.

Comment: I'd be more interested why the uncommented version throws that error. Is that app.config from the test project? What about the config file in the bin/Debug directory for the test project? Does it look correct?